# Future of statistical methods in image segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, image-segmentation

I was looking for a purely statistical method for image segmentation and found many, e.g. Hidden Markov Random Fields with EM algorithm. But it seems to me that these methods are nowadays completely turned down by neural nets.
Is it right or is there still something where statistical methods can excel in image segmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to use some sort of graphical model on-top of the segmentations output by a CNN to fine-tune and output the final prediction. (See "DeepLab" models)

Also, aren't neural networks statistical models as well?

Comment: They are very different when you are writing the grant application or applying for a job. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I usually think of neural nets as a more black-box thing than pure statistical algorithms as K-means etc. But you can surely correct me :)